# How do I set the correct path when using include function

Tags: php, css

I am making a template for other pages to use.  The source files that contains the include command are on different levels of directory. For example...

templates are help in:

```
/template/
```

pages are located in:

```
/services/
```

and:

```
/services/products/
```

and:

```
/services/products/dishwasher
```

So the statement I wrote was:

```
include (__DIR__ . "/../template/header.php");
```

I am testing locally is this an issue?

This only allows for /services/ to include the requested file, the lower sub domains do not get it.  I also have the problem for pictures and css js files. Is there a work around?

Comment: Have you tried it in any of the subdirectories? I have a hunch it will work if you haven't, and if you have and it doesn't then the answer I'm writing is dead wrong.

Comment: yes i have tried it in sub directories, header footer not included, only works one level down.

Comment: If you dont use an sub directory for application (ex : site.com/app/template/service/), you dont have a problem :)

you can use "/" for css and js files on first char of path (src="/js/blabla.js")

Answer (score 3):

You can call an include file on any page, at any level in the hierarchy, with something like this:

```
<?php include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/template/header.php"; ?>
```

… where `/template/header.php` is the full path from the root folder to your `header.php` file.

Comment: tried it locally and uploaded it. didnt work same problem. Also doesnt work on one level deep now either.

Comment: yes, nut it also did not work on the server when i uploaded it which is a concern.

Comment: What kind of platform are you on? Apache is assumed here. This is a standard setup and works well, so some information might be missing here.